# Codeigniter Png images don't show

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I can't show png images in codeigniter. I can show from the same folder jpg/jpeg images but not png. I searched on google but seems like no one has the same problem. Is it htaccess or config problem?
Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]  
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images)
```

This was all i needed for my png to show its a wierd bug.

Comment: Show your `.htaccess` as a beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that base_dir and base_path not entered correctly:

Check out your `config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourpath/'; 
$config['base_path'] = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\yourpath\\";
```

or on Linux

```
$config['base_path'] = "/home/user/yourpath";
```

Then check your source using `img` tag:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>/image/logo.png" />
```

Check out .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourdomain.com/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Very usefull still i can't use this because i have background image in css that are png. Still there is nothing wrong since i can't access even with direct link the png images. But the jpeg i can.

Comment: Did you checked your CSS file via Firebug for a PNG file is loaded? Check out this: `background:url(../images/your_file.png);` Try to test some arbitrary png file and load directly in URI.

Comment: Yes i modified you'r htacess a little and seems that did the trick. Thank you i will mark it as answer.